# Replace script on Unity object with different subtype?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Given a base class A and a inherited class of B.

If a prefab has a script of type A attached to it, is there any way I can change the type of the script to B?

Having to manually remove the script and add the different type will wipe the script position and all custom values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick workaround, I found that it's fairly easy to write a console app to edit the .prefab files, which is also a ton faster than using the editor if you have a bunch of prefabs to change.

```c#
var pathToPrefabs = @"PATHTOFOLDER";
var searchPattern = "*.prefab";

var oldGuid = "f918e74538022b447823e4cf64700632"; //the old 'guid references in the prefab file'
var newGuid = "f597f3f375d88c645ad124f7cbcd1322"; //the new guid of the new type

foreach (var prefab in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pathToPrefabs, searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(prefab);
    text = text.Replace(oldGuid, newGuid);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(prefab, text);
}
```

To get the right guids, simply do the change manually on one prefab, then look at the git code changes.

Worked a treat.

NOTE: this will only work if you have your assets serialized to text (which you should do if you are using source control).

Answer (score 1):

I used Rider find in files (replace option) and it found all the meta, prefab and scene info with the old GUID and replaced it with the new GUID and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can also right-click on the inspector, and select "debug" view.
Then the option to change the script is enabled.